# Google search showing "Index of /. cgi-bin/"

Tags: google, html, google-search, namecheap

I recently decided to leave GoDaddy in choice of NameCheap as my preferred hosting package for my mothers business, I also had to bring my domain name to the guys i register my local domain names.

Once I had finally gotten control of my domain name I changed the DNS settings and set up the hosting package and waited for the domain name to resolve.. 24/48 Hrs (as I wasn't in a big rush) later I went back to check and found it had finally resolved.

I then uploaded the old site that used to be hosted with godaddy via ftp to my nameCheap server... However once I had done this I decided to search for my mums business on Google and found it looked like this

[image]

So I logged into ftp and found the cgi-bin and deleted it thinking that was the problem.. but still no luck. If you click the link it takes you to index.html perfectly... its just in the search result I have this weird erro, any idea how to fix would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/42622/google-search-showing-index-of-cgi-bin?newreg=b7e164ae192a462f921d08b558ebe276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means you didn't have a valid index file last time google crawled your site and  /. cgi-bin/ was accessible without an index file itself.

That should sort itself out with no problem as long as the public html folder has a valid index file.

Comment: ahh.. root folder... I uploaded everything into the **"public_html"** file of the webserver via ftp is that correct? or should I just upload everything to the root location... its been about 5 days now and no change to that listing? is that normal..

Comment: That's what I meant. Sure that's correct. Submit a sitemap to webmaster tools on google, and fetch as google to ensure the index gets crawled again asap, and the description and title tags sure be updated on search results.

Comment: BTW, it appears updated here: Auckland Screen Printing, North Shore Screen Printing, We specilise in Nylon printing, Umbrella printing, t shirt printing and promotional products. We screen ...

Comment: oh okay.. well thanks for your Response I will resubmit my sitemap tonight and hope it changes what I am seeing.. I just dumped my browser cache in case it was that.. still nothing.. actually maybe i should log out of chrome/gmail account thingy.... I will give it a try and see if that works..

Comment: no luck.. site map it is..

Comment: Google is probably serving you a not updated description of your site, but don't worry, give it some time, it'll definitely change.

Comment: That's balonies... I am having this issue with many of my sites, on top of that Google labels my sites as "hacked", no matter what I do, no matter where I switch my DNS, site, platform it keeps happening. This is some kind of "bug" with Google crawler. Funny when you do "fetch by Google" site comes back to normal.... https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/d/msgid/webmasters/e83e1929-fea7-44f3-8649-3d965942a838%40googleproductforums.com?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer

Answer (score 0):

The error “Index of /. cgi-bin/” means that the DNS zone hasn't got updated yet and that you don't have an index file in your public_html directory.